# How to set order of x-axis on sns histplot?

Tags: python, jupyter, histogram, axis-labels

The 'floorType' was originally character variable that I changed into integer (1,2,3,4,5) through Excel.

But when I loaded that cvs. file into Jupyter and draw sns histogram of this variable, the order of axis is shown as (4 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1) but not (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5) as I expected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOTOp.png)

Please teach me how to set the x-axis of the histogram (sns_python) in ascending order.

Comment: you can't sort in ascending order inside the sns.histplot. There is no parameter for that, you have to sort in ascending order beforehand.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_xticks` on seaborn functions like `histplot` by assigning this object `a` name and passing it the argument as a `list` (e.g. ticks ordered 1 through 5):

```
a = sns.histplot(data_drop['floortype'], discrete=True)
a.set_xticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of the code?